# How to parse Json in C# Web as open Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

net and i just want to read a Json and want to update or add the nodes in JSON. I have used Angular and PHP for this and i was able to read and write the file easily. But My server is now IIS, So i want to parse JSON file on C# and want to change the values in it.

I googled a lot and found a lot of solution for JSON.NET or Newtonsoft.Json. I have only one index.aspx page, where i am successfully able to read the json file as below

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("json/myJsonFile.json"));
Response.Write(json);
```

And this is printing JSON text in web easily. But i am not able to parse it properly. I am writing code in Notepad++, as i don't have Visual Studio and don't want to install. I heard that .net code is open source now, So i tried this from Notepad++. Now please let me know, how to Parse JSON without using Visual Studio?

My code in more detail is as below

> index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
   <form action="index.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
       <input type="text" id="empname" name="empname" placeholder="Enter Full Name"/>
       <p><button id="addBtn" class="btn btn-success" onclick='return addEmployee()' type="submit">Add</button> &nbsp;<button id="removeBtn" class="btn btn-success" onclick='removeEmployee()'>Remove</button></p>
   </form>
<%
   string ename = Request.Form["empname"];
   string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("json/myJsonFile.json"));
   Response.Write(json);
   //Here i want to parse JSON file
%>
</body>
</html>
```

> Javascript

```
function addEmployee()
{
  if($("#empname").val() == "")
  {
      alert("Please type Name.");
      $("#empname").focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

> JSON

```
[
   {
    "ID": "ID01",
    "Name": "First One"
   },
   {
     "ID": "ID02",
     "Name": "Second One"
    }
]
```

Remember i am writing code in Notepad++, So please let me know accordingly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have good reason not to install VS, but just to make sure you know, VS2015 is free.

Comment: I am sorry but i can not install Visual Studio, Is there any way to make my solution?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If I understood correctly, you need to:
- parse JSON file, which you are using as a data store
- add a new employee to aforesaid JSON store
- save JSON back to disk

Right?

Comment: Yes Perttu. I need to parse JSON as Array or object, so that i can update JSON data and write back to the json file.

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable with C# (it actually is very uncomfortable to work with C# without any tools), an alternative would be to just stick with PHP; just install PHP for IIS: http://php.iis.net

If you want to stick with C# but don't want to use Visual Studio, get a text editor that is supported by http://www.omnisharp.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScriptSerializer has been deprecated and [Microsoft recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) using Json.NET.

Download [Json.NET here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

In your aspx page link to Json.NET:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Newtonsoft.Json"  %>
<%@ Import namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" %>
```

Make a class for Employee:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Add a reference to Json.NET:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Deserialize your Json from disk:

```
List<Employee> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(json);

// ...

list.Add(employee);

// deserialize + save
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```